# String or character input from command line in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    char str[1000], ch[100]; 
    int i, frequency = 0;
    strcpy(argv[1],str);
    strcpy(argv[2], ch);
    for(i = 0; str[i]!= '\0'; ++i) 
    { 
        if(ch[i] == str[i]) 
            ++frequency; 
    } 
    printf("Frequency of %c = %d", *ch, frequency); 
    return (0); 
}
```

Compiles succesfully.

Input: Hello h
The output is: Frequency of Somegarbage = 2

Comment: Please format your code correctly, exactly as the samples in your C textbook.

Comment: Please [edit] your question on tell us what output you expect for what input. Show us some examples.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't require to copy the entire string into another one for any manipulations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{
    if(argc==3)
    {
        int i, frequency = 0;
        for(i = 0; argv[1][i]!= '\0'; ++i)
        {
            if(argv[1][i] == argv[2][0])
                ++frequency;
        }
        printf("Frequency of %c = %d", argv[2][0], frequency);

    }
    else
        printf("Invalid no of inputs\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
hello h
```

**Output:**

```
Frequency of h = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You are copying in the wrong direction, the prototype is

```
char * strcpy(char *destination, const char *source);
```

This is very likely undefined behavior.

Also there's no need to copy the strings, you can process the arguments like any other string.

Comment: I am sorry i am new to command-line arguments, can you please tell me how to give an input through command lines? I use atoi() function when it is an integer, but i am unable to give user defined string or char input from command line. Thank you

Comment: Do not use `atoi`, since its behavior on invalid input is not reliable.  Use `strtol`.

Comment: @PranavKarakavalasa Please post a new actual question, using comments to follow up with something completely different is not how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` function copies the values of second argument to first argument. If you want to use or access the value(**single character**) from the command line argument, then its just like two dimensional array.

```
argv[1][0]
```

I am thinking you didn't understand the command line argument well. In command line it doesn't mean you type number,character or string. It will always be read as a string. therefore if u have some command to run such as

```
./file-name 123 a myfile 3.14
```

All above will accessed as follows:

**agrv[ 1 ]** is string having **"123"**. To access first character(**'1'**) only I will write **argv[1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm)[0]**.

**agrv[2]** is string having **"a"**. To access first character(**'a'**) only I will write **argv[1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm)[0]**.

**agrv[3]** is string having **"myfile"**. To access first character(**'m'**) only I will write **argv[3][0]**.

**agrv[4]** is string having **"3.14"**. To access first character(**'3'**) only I will write **argv[4][0]**.

you can also see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm) for more information about command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

As [unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind) pointed out, you are copying with [`strcpy()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) in the wrong direction.

```
strcpy(argv[1],str);
strcpy(argv[2], ch);
```

should be changed to

```
strcpy(str, argv[1]);
strcpy(ch, argv[2]);
```

This is how I my teacher taught me: Right to left. Like the way Usain Bolt points when posing his famous [victory pose](http://content.newsinc.com/jpg/3163/31444970/44209623.jpg?t=1474999440). His right hand points to the left.

[`strncpy()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncpy.htm) can be used to avoid overflows instead of `strcpy()` but if the source is longer than the specified size, no `\0` is appended to the destination string by `strncpy()`.

You appear to be trying to give a string and a character as input via the command line and find the number of occurrences of that character in the string.

If that's the case, supposing `argv[1]` has the string and `argv[2]` has the character,
if `argv[2]` is not a single character, an error message may be displayed.

```
if(strlen(argv[2])!=1)
{
    printf("\nError");
    exit(1);
}
```

You should also check if the number of arguments provided (other than the program name) is at least 2. For example, if only one argument was given and you try to use `argv[2]`, it would lead to error.

```
if(argc<3)
{
    printf("\nNo enough arguments");
}
```

The name of the program counts as a value in `argv[0]`. See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm)

```
char c=ch[0];
for(i = 0; str[i]!= '\0'; ++i) 
{ 
    if(c == str[i]) 
        ++frequency; 
} 
printf("Frequency of %c = %d", c, frequency);
```

Using `ch[0]` instead of `c` should work as well.

Comment: "strncpy() can be used to avoid overflows" and also does not insure the destination is a null character terminated string.  Not good advise unless details of proper use are shown.

Comment: @chux I didn't know that. But thanks to you now I do. Edited.